# Problema con los formatos de las fechas al exportar de Oracle a python con PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, date, formato

Os dejo aquí una pregunta a ver si podeis ayudarme.

Tengo un problema con los formatos de las fechas. en la base de datos la columna fechas viene como: 22/06/01 con el formato YY/MM/DD pero al extraerlo a python mediante pandas, se me exporta con formato DD/MM/YY identificando, por ejemplo, como si estuvieramos en el dia 22 de junio de 2001 lo que hace imposible poder hacer busquedas.
Llevo un tiempo buscando maneras pero soy incapaz.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.
Un saludo

Comment: ¿Y el código? Si la columna en Oracle es de tipo Fecha, lo que muestra es solo una visualización para humanos, internamente se maneja como una fecha real y puede ser exportada con el formato que le digas. Si es un *varchar*, bueno, habrá que hacer conversiones.

Comment: Gracias por responder, Es un DATE, la sentencia que uso para la consulta es: "SELECT ac_mensual.art_codigo, ac_mensual.fecha FROM ac_mensual WHERE ac_mensual.art_codigo ='183622' AND ac_mensual.fecha >='22/06/01'" y me salen registros con fechas                                                                      22/12/01
22/11/01
22/10/01
22/09/01
22/07/01
21/12/01
21/11/01
21/10/01
21/09/01
21/08/01
21/07/01                                                                                                                        Es decir, del año 2022 y del año 2021 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como puse en el comentario y que confirmas en el tuyo, al ser tipo `DATE`, Oracle maneja el campo de fecha con su algoritmo interno. Lo que tu ves en la salida de algún visualizador es solo una representación para humanos.

Entonces hay que convertir la fecha dada a formato DATE con la instrucción [TO_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html):

```sql
SELECT ac_mensual.art_codigo, ac_mensual.fecha 
FROM ac_mensual 
WHERE ac_mensual.art_codigo ='183622' 
AND ac_mensual.fecha >= TO_DATE('22/06/01', 'YY/MM/DD')
```